# Unexpectedly closed channel in sync::mpsc

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, closures, message-queue

I have a closure, that uses `Sender` from `std::sync::mpsc`:

```
let node = Arc::new(Mutex::new(node_sender)); 
let switch_callback =
        move |p| match Params::parse::<Value>(p) {
            Ok(ref v) if v.as_array().is_some() => {
                let chain = v.as_array()
                    .and_then(|arr| arr[0].as_str())
                    .and_then(|s| Some(s.to_owned()))
                    .unwrap();

                let channel = node.lock().unwrap().clone();
                match channel.send(chain.clone()) {
                    Ok(_) => futures::done(Ok(Value::String(chain))).boxed(),
                    Err(err) => futures::failed(JsonRpcError::invalid_params(
                        format!("Node not responding: {}", err.to_string())))
                        .boxed(),
                }
            }
            Ok(_) | Err(_) => {
                futures::failed(JsonRpcError::invalid_params("Invalid chain label for node"))
                    .boxed()
            }
        };
```

This closure is used as a callback from another thread. I used `clone()` here, to clone `Sender` so I expect the channel should stay active. But the channel is actually getting closed, why would this happen?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.* Please review how to create a [MCVE]. The code you have presented does nothing because it creates a closure which is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility for this would be that your `Receiver` has been dropped. The channel will only stay active while both the `Sender` and `Receiver` are alive.

One of the examples for [`Sender.send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#method.send) shows that dropping the `Receiver` terminates the channel:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

let (tx, rx) = channel();

// This send is always successful
tx.send(1).unwrap();

// This send will fail because the receiver is gone
drop(rx);
assert_eq!(tx.send(1).unwrap_err().0, 1);
```

Make sure your `Receiver` is alive for as long as your `Sender` is and you should not see this error.